# unauthorized access 401 during browsing of site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, unauthorized, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I currently have an issue, where if someone tries to access my domain www.adomain.com and try to get to the login page, they're sometimes redirected to:
'www.adomain.com/?ReturnUrl=%2f'. This results in a 401 - Unauthorized Access.

I've tried to add a defaultUrl in the web.config thinking that that might fix it, but it hasn't.
I've also tried to add a redirect to the login page if the user gets a 401 page, but there's 2 issues with this:
1. it didn't work.
2. even if it did work it could result in an infinite loop of redirects.

For some reason my users & tester can reproduce it in chrome & edge by manually going to 'www.adomain.com/?ReturnUrl=%2f' & ocassionally during regular usage of the site but unfortunately I can only reproduce it in Chrome, when going to said url, during usual browsing on the site nothing happens.

Authentication section in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Login" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="720" />
</authentication>
```